# BCB6 How to display long date from DataSet Field in label?

Tags: date, c++builder, display

I have a problem with displaying the correct date from a `TDataSet`.

In a `TDataSet`, I have a date in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format. On the computer, I have set the date in the `d.mm.yy` format, and so it has to stay, I can not change it.

Now, I have to take the date in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` from the `TDataSet` and display it in a `TLabel` component in this format, but it always shows me the date in the `'YY-MM-DD'` format, and that if the date is before 1969 then it adds 100 years.

I have my date in:

```
MyData->DataSet->Fields->FieldByName("date")
```

In my DB, my date is in `YYYY-MM-YY` format.

On my machine, I have the short date set to the `'DD-MM-YY'` format, but I need to display my date in the label in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.

I have no ideas for how to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

`TDateTime` has a method named `FormatString()`. You can do this:

```
MyData->DataSet->Fields->FieldByName(L"date")->AsDateTime.FormatString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: @forritarik Could you please accept the answer then. Thank you